# iOS SceneKit - photo set as model's diffuse content not rendering correctly

Tags: ios, scenekit

I have an iOS app with a model of an iPhone case.
I'm using SceneKit to display the model.
I set the iPhone's case diffuse property content to be that of my image.
From some reason on the edges of the model the photo rendered doesn't look right, it's as if the back wrapping is wrong.

When opening the same model with a texture of an image using Blender or 3dmax (on Windows) it looks fine. What could be the issue?

Wrong rendering of image as appears in the image here -

[image: image with incorrect texture display]

Comment: Does your image has transparent area? If so you probably need to turn off double sided with material.doubleSided = NO; or make the image opaque.

Comment: I've already set : material.doubleSided = NO. Do you think it has to do with the image peeping from the other side?

Comment: can you please post a picture of the texture and what the expected result is (as seen in Blender for instance) ? You can also check your texture coordinates in the SceneKit scene editor : http://i.stack.imgur.com/Eeo5k.jpg